# Declaring global variables without a value

Tags: javascript, variables, global-variables

I wish to create a JavaScript object with nested global variables where some of the variables will not have a default value specified.

I currently have this:

```
var globalVarA = "foo";
var globalVarB = "bar";
var globalVarC;

function myFunction(){
  //do something
}
```

I wish to change this to:

```
var myObject = {
  GlobalVars: {
     globalVarA: "foo",
     globalVarB: "bar",
     globalVarC
  },
  myFunction: function(){
     //do something
  }
}
```

However I get the following error:

> Expected ':'

How can I declare this variable without a value?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to define the variables as properties of `GlobalVars` you have to explicitly assign `undefined` to them

```
GlobalVars: {
     globalVarA: "foo",
     globalVarB: "bar",
     globalVarC: undefined
  },
```

Your code contained invalid notation, when using object literal notation you must specify a value for each variable. This is unlike other notations like XML or formParams where you can declare a attribute/property without setting it.

Note, that in my solution undefined variables do get a default value - that value is just the primitive value `undefined` which is what is returned by default for variables that were not defined.

However, your variable *does* get defined if you do `globalVarC: undefined`

```
GlobalVars.globalVarC;//undefined
GlobalVars.globalVarX;//undefined
GlobalVars.hasOwnProperty("globalVarC");//true
GlobalVars.hasOwnProperty("globalVarX");//false
```

From the [spec](https://es5.github.io/#x4.3.9):

> 4.3.9 undefined value:
>
> primitive value used when a variable has not been assigned a value.

Comment: Just on a side note. What would be the downside to not declaring `globalVarC` at all until it is required? Since you can set `GlobalVars.globalVarC = "whatever";' even if it is not declared.

Comment: @TimBJames that's an excellent question. For example, the difference might be expressed in an `hasOwnProperty` check. Personally, if it's just for use in that function, in my own code I'd do `GlobalVars.globalVarC` instead of explicitly setting it to undefined.

Comment: Yeah I would probably go with also, because if you are checking for the existence of the variable, you would check `if ( GlobalVars.globalVarC != undefined)` which would be the case either way.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a value for `globalVarC` else the javascript syntax for json will be wrong, since you do not have any value to initialize you can give the value [undefined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined).

`undefined` is a global variable with primitive value **undefined**.

```
var myObject = {
  GlobalVars: {
     globalVarA: "foo",
     globalVarB: "bar",
     globalVarC: undefined
  },
  myFunction: function(){
     //do something
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want the `undefined` primitive value to be the default value:

```
var myObject = {
  GlobalVars: {
     globalVarA: "foo",
     globalVarB: "bar",
     globalVarC: void 0
  },
  myFunction: function(){
     //do something
  }
}
```

The `void 0` expression gives the value of `undefined`, regardless of whether `undefined` was "rerouted".

Comment: Just wondering.. Doesn't that invoke the JS compiler on the value 0? I never really got why you would change the value of undefined. On that same train of thought, one could change the value of Function.prototype.call. Would you do this in production code yourself? What advantages does it offer? I hope this doesn't come off as aggressive, I'm really interested in why you'd do that.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum What do you mean by "invoke the compiler on value 0"? As for changing `undefined`, surely nobody has any good reason to do that ;-)

Comment: the `void` operator invokes the JavaScript compiler on the following expression (in this case `0` which is cast to `"0"` and returns `undefined`).  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void . Invoking the compiler seems a bit extreme in this case imho. Even `globalVarC: (function(){var a;return a;})()` seems cleaner. I'll make a perf :)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum `(function(a) { return a; }());` is shorter, though I doubt any performance issues will surface by using `void` :)

Comment: To my surprise, void is actually faster than an anonymous function in chrome :) Thought I'd let you know