# How to tell the difference between undeclared and undefined JavaScript object properties?

Tags: javascript, web, undefined

So is there no way to check if an object property has been formally declared vs not?? For example...

```
var obj={};

console.log( non_existent_variable ) //throws not defined error
console.log( obj.non_existent_property) //no error,===undefined
```

Consider the following...

```
 function m(){
   this.prop;
 }
 var MyObj=new m();
```

In this case, I think there should be a knowable difference between MyObj.prop which has been formally declared, and MyObj.non_existent_property which has not.

Unfortunately they both ===undefined, both return false with hasOwnProperty and neither are enumerated in a for( in ) loop.
Anything I'm missing?

(IMHO, why couldn't the parser set declared but unset properties to null? 
What would be the harm in that?)

Comment: Right, because object properties are not "declared", they are either set or unset. What is declared is the object itself.

Comment: What do you mean, "*both return false with hasOwnProperty*"? Then they simply aren't existent.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15523638/declaring-variables-without-a-value

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In both your examples, the properties have **not** been "formally declared".  You have to assign something, even if what you do is `undefined`:

```js
function MyObject() {
    this.m = undefined; 
}

var sampleMyObject = new MyObject();

console.log(sampleMyObject.m); // undefined
console.log(sampleMyObject.hasOwnProperty('m')); // true
console.log('m' in sampleMyObject); // true
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var):

> Undeclared variables do not exist until the code assigning to them is executed.

Comment: Yeah, I should have put declared in quotes. I just couldn't think of another way of describing what I meant. What are the reasons to set to undefined rather than null?

Comment: @user2782001: You'll have to pick what you think will be best for your project. Whichever you pick, be consistent. I would personally go with `undefined` because it implies exactly what it means: that the property has not yet been defined. If you set them to `null`, then they *are* defined.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize to null, then you have a difference.

Comment: Yes, clearly. Which leads to my opinion that it would be nice if the parser automatically set properties to null when 'declared' but not set.